# GLSL: will compiler evaluate functions with constant arguments?

Tags: opengl, optimization, compilation

If I have the following code in a GLSL fragment shader:

```
float r = 0.386;
float a = 26.6;
float xd = r*cos(0.0174532924*(a+0));
float yd = r*sin(0.0174532924*(a+0));
float xe = r*cos(0.0174532924*(a+90));
float ye = r*sin(0.0174532924*(a+90));
```

is it a sane assumption that the compiler will evaluate those trigonometric functions instead of have them be evaluated in every fragment execution?

Comment: depends on the optimization level and the compiler, but did you tried looking at the assembly?

Comment: if you only need them calculated once, why not calculate them and send to a uniform variable or UBO?

Comment: I actually could just calculate it with my calculator and directly assing xd, yd, xe, ye these values - but if I can rely on the compiler I would like to leave the code in this state for self-documentation purposes.

Comment: If you could calculate it and directly assign it then you definitely want to just do this through a uniform variable. I'll post an answer explaining

Answer (score 1):

In this case, sadly, you can't know much, since the compilation is done by the GPU. I would say it is implementation dependent, since some compilers may be better optimized.

However, as WearyWanderer sayed, you can hardcode the values or pass them through uniforms/UBO.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned you could calculate the values and directly assign them, but want to let it for documentation purposes, I assum the values will be the same in every execution of the shader code.

Uniform Variables are variables that you can calculate once, send to a shader, and are the same for every execution, unless you change the uniform variable at some point. For example:

```
    float r = 0.386;
    float a = 26.6;

    float xd_val = r*cos(0.0174532924*(a+0));
    GLuint xd_id = glGetUniformLocation(pShaderProgram, "xd");
    glUniform1f(xd_id, xd_val);
```

This calculates the value only once on the CPU, passes it to the shader program as a uniform variable, and the shader has access to the value for every execution without recaulcating it, but still leaves the code in here for your documentation that you wanted.

Uniform's are commonly used for object wide values, I.E an alpha-value, passing in scene lights for phong shader model, etc.